# TWRP can not find my backup ROM files

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp

I am trying to flash my backup ROM – but when I click "Restore" in TWRP, it doesn't find my files. What am I doing wrong?

[image: TWRP] [image: TWRP NO RESTORE!!!] [image: TWRP]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Backups from TWRP are kept in the TWRP - BACKUPS folder, so I have to ask, is anything in the BACKUPS folder?

Comment: No. I MOVED the backups out of TWRP and ONTO my pc THEN MOVED the files BACK onto the TWRP sdcard. Thats when It wont recognize the rom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TWRP has a file manager by default in Advanced section... I'd suggest that you do a backup as is, and then use the file manager to move the Backup in exactly the same place that TWRP just made  !

Make backup 1
Move backup 2 to backup 1
Restore backup 2